# Selecting drop down value from <li>

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I have a dropdown which contains number of options and among them I have to select one and click on them, For this I am using the below code but it gives me the below error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Below is the code which I have written.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#select2-religion-container")).click(); //religion dd click

        List <WebElement> listReligion = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#select2-religion-results>li"));

        System.out.println(listReligion.size());

        String MyReligion = "Christian";
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".select2-search__field")).sendKeys(MyReligion);
        for(int i=0 ; i< listReligion.size() ; i++) {
            if(list.get(i).getText().equals(MyReligion)) {
                list.get(i).click();
            }
        }
```

and below is the error which I am getting.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port 27881
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1589711914.821][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 81.
[1589711916.986][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
May 17, 2020 4:08:39 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-1QASA0A', ip: '192.168.1.129', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '14'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 81.0.4044.138, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Ravindra\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:54230}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: b5a9fe1bdf075b210b84066d6246d456
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getText(RemoteWebElement.java:166)
    at com.RDK.qa.testcases.SampleTestRDK.main(SampleTestRDK.java:94)
```

Below is the HTML DOM

```html
<ul class="select2-results__options" role="listbox" id="select2-religion-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false"><li class="select2-results__option" role="option" aria-disabled="true" data-select2-id="799">Select Religion</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-religion-result-m0f4-Hindu" role="option" aria-selected="true" data-select2-id="select2-religion-result-m0f4-Hindu">Hindu</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-religion-result-wjht-Muslim - Shia" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-religion-result-wjht-Muslim - Shia">Muslim - Shia</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-religion-result-b75a-Muslim - Sunni" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-religion-result-b75a-Muslim - Sunni">Muslim - Sunni</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-religion-result-m5xr-Muslim - Others" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-religion-result-m5xr-Muslim - Others">Muslim - Others</li><li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" id="select2-religion-result-2s26-Christian" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-religion-result-2s26-Christian">Christian</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-religion-result-osni-Sikh" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-religion-result-osni-Sikh">Sikh</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-religion-result-np6g-Jain - Digambar" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-religion-result-np6g-Jain - Digambar">Jain - Digambar</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-religion-result-a2ie-Jain - Shwetambar" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-religion-result-a2ie-Jain - Shwetambar">Jain - Shwetambar</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-religion-result-ugt0-Jain - Others" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-religion-result-ugt0-Jain - Others">Jain - Others</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-religion-result-pbl6-Parsi" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-religion-result-pbl6-Parsi">Parsi</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-religion-result-4jon-Buddhist" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-religion-result-4jon-Buddhist">Buddhist</li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-religion-result-y89i-Inter-Religion" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-religion-result-y89i-Inter-Religion">Inter-Religion</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stale element usually occurs if the DOM is changed after you have created the element and if the element has got deleted from DOM or if its no longer present in DOM.

So in your scenario,It looks like you have initially created listReligion and then searched for the Reglion . And then only religions matching your search will be shown in the UI. as a result some elements will get deleted that might be reason for your Stale element Exception.

Place the list listReligions line below SendKeys and try running it.

Try the below lines .

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".select2-search__field")).sendKeys(MyReligion);
List <WebElement> listReligion = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#select2-religion-results>li"));
```

Comment: can you paste the full code and complete error log? My guess is that it might be throwing the exception even before it reached the code that you have pasted here

Comment: from the error log it i throwing error in your getText in line 94 in the file.Can you show that line and the lines before it?